# Datastage job failed netezza to greenplum data load using ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver

Tags: odbc, netezza, greenplum, datastage

Greenplum_Connector_0,0: The following SQL statement failed: INSERT INTO GPCC_TT_20211121154035261_15420_0_XXXXX_TABLE_NAME (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,...) SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,... FROM GPCC_ET_20211121154035417_15420_0. The statement reported the following reason: [SQLCODE=HY000][Native=3,484,948] [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: missing data for column "xyz_id"  (seg2 slice1 192.168.0.0:00 pid=30826)(Where External table gpcc_et_20211121154035417_15420_0, line 91 of gpfdist://ABCD:123/DDCETLMIG_15420_gpw_3_3_20211121154035261: "AG?199645?ABCD EFGH. - HELLOU - JSF RT ADF?MMM?+1?A?DAD. SDA?0082323209?N?N..."; File copy.c; Line 5211; Routine NextCopyFromX; )

Comment: In data there is a new line char(spl char), which is causing the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to read the error message carefully.  Somehow your job has managed not to provide a value for column xyz_id.  Check your job design thoroughly.

Comment: Hey Mr. Ray, Thanks for your reply. Here, new line char(spl char), which is causing the problem. meta data (column and data type)wise there is no change in source and target, we are just performing select * insert into a destination. Could be a driver config issue.